# In ngx translate, can I know how to embed a parameter inside a html tag

Tags: html, angular, ngx-translate

**In HTML**

`<h1> {{'common.Hi' | translate}} <span whitelabel></span> </h1>`

I need the whitelabel selector to be embedded to the translating sentence without it being seperate

**In the json file**

"Hi": "Hi everyone"

Answer (score 0):

In the json file

```
"Hi": "Hi everyone<span whitelabel></span>"
```

In the HTML:

```
<h1  [innerHTML]="'common.Hi' | translate"></h1>
```

Comment: This will not work. It will consider it as a string, not as a HTML element.

Comment: No it will inject the html span inside the h1 tag. https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#5-use-html-tags